# foreach only running function (`sendThis`) for first item in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to send each item in an array to a function. The function is a curl request, but I don't think that matters.

```
$a=array('string1','string2');
foreach ($a as $value) {
    sendThis($value);
}
```

That code runs the function just once for the first item in the array (`string1`). How do I keep this running for every item in the array?

`sendThis` function is similar to the following:

```
function sendThis($value){
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.xyz.com/v2/users/".$value."/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: XYZ123",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;

}}
```

Comment: I think there might be a problem in your `sendThis()` function. If you replace the `sendThis($value);` part with `echo "$value<br>";` you can see that it prints out both items in your array

Comment: You're right @Aniket. Updating with my function now....

Comment: @mdfst13 I didn't think that would be the issue at all, but apparently it was. Updated my question.

Comment: @jonmrich it seems to be working just fine for me. It goes through all the elements. PS: Remove the comma after you make the array for `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. Is there any errors you are getting?

Comment: So in the $response, it gets back two response @Aniket? I can only ever get the first

Comment: Actually...it seems like it's only `echo` ing the response once, but if I try to do a DELETE or POST, it works on both.

Comment: When I test your code (and also removing that comma I spoke about earlier), it visits everything in the string. I recommend you try the code snippet (just by itself) you've posted. You'll see it works.